# Spring Boot Starter GraphQL OPTIONS Pre-Flight request rejected with HTTP 403

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graphql, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I've recently converted a GraphQL API from SpringBoot Web to WebFlux. In the previous version, the @RequestMapping was annotated with @CrossOrigin, which seemed to cover the OPTIONS HTTP verb.

In the new version, I am using the @MutationMapping / @QueryMapping annotations to map the schema to my methods, and responding to them reactively.

The problem is that for some of our frontend's, an OPTIONS preflight is sent and rejected with a 403 by this new implementation.

[image: Options request 403 response]

Is there an annotation or configuration I can enable where this preflight will not be rejected?

I've attempted to use the GraphQlWebFluxAutoConfiguration.GraphQlEndpointCorsConfiguration object however I can't seem to get it configured correctly. Any advice would be much appreciated, as I'm relatively new to the WebFlux stack.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it - the issue was caused by my local dev environment having tomcat9, and the staging/qa environment I was deploying to having tomcat7 (not supporting WebFlux properly).

Please note that the app.enable-cors is a property defined in my application.properties file - you will need to add this if you are just copying+pasting this code.

I created two configuration classes, overriding both the Mvc and WebFlux Configurer.addCorsMapping(CorsRegistry registry) method. Depending on which auto configuration is loaded, the correct overriden method will be run. Code as follows:

First, the WebFlux version

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer;

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "app.enable-cors", havingValue = "true")
public class GraphQLWebFluxConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry){
        corsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

Secondly the MVC version

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "app.enable-cors", havingValue = "true")
public class GraphQLWebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry){
        corsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

I obviously have this disabled for the prod environment, but as a workaround for your QA/local environment it works well.